# Groovy Map of Lists into List of Maps

Tags: list, dictionary, groovy

So essentially I have something like this:

```
[a: ["c","d"], b: ["e","f"]]
```

The amount of items in each list is arbitrary. If there is only one item the list is no longer a list and it is a string.

I want to turn it into:

```
[ [a:"c", b:"e"], [a:"d",b:"f"] ]
```

I don't really care if the solution uses Groovy methods or not. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Share the code what you have tried so far...

Comment: I don't have any code because I'm stumped on a nice way to do it. I was hoping there were some built in methods to use.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's another way to do it, that I think is less obscure while still being fairly concise:

```
def ml = [a: ["c","d"], b: ["e","f"]]

// Create an empty list that creates empty maps as needed
def lm = [].withDefault{ [:] }

ml.each{ k, values ->
    [values].flatten().eachWithIndex { value, index ->
        lm[index][k] = value
    }
}

assert lm == [[a:"c", b:"e"], [a:"d", b:"f"]]
```

If you don't want or cannot use `withDefault` (because you don't want the list to grow automatically), then this works too:

```
def ml = [a: ["c","d"], b: ["e","f"]]

def lm = []

ml.each{ k, values ->
    [values].flatten().eachWithIndex { value, index ->
        lm[index] = lm[index] ?: [:]
        lm[index][k] = value
    }
}

assert lm == [[a:"c", b:"e"], [a:"d", b:"f"]]
```

---

**Edit**: Added code to handle strings not contained within a list.

Note, the given trick (`[values].flatten().eachWithIndex{...}`) is not necessarily very efficient.  If speed is essential, then using this would be slightly faster at the expense of readability:

```
(values instanceof List ? values : [values]).eachWithIndex{...}
```

Comment: Ok the `withDefault` is what I was missing. This still doesnt handle the case of the value being a string, so here is the udpated code: `  if (values instanceof ArrayList) {
    values.eachWithIndex { value, index ->         
      lm[index][k] = value     
    }
  }  else {
    lm[0][k] = values
  }`

Comment: OK, that was kinda buried in your original question, but I see it now.  Just an FYI: you would be better using `values instanceof List`, since it's more flexible if you needed to change the List at a later date.

Answer (score 7):

One-liner, assuming x = `[a: ["c","d"], b: ["e","f"]]` or x = `[a: "b", c: "d"]`:

```
[x*.key, x*.value].transpose()*.combinations().transpose()*.flatten()*.toSpreadMap()
```

How this works:

First, split the keys and values:

`[x*.key, x*.value]` = `[[a, b], [[c, d], [e, f]]]`

Transpose them to pair up keys and values:

`[[a, b], [[c, d], [e, f]]].transpose()` = `[[a, [c, d]], [b, [e, f]]]`

Use `combinations` to pair up the key with its values (spread operator used here to apply it to each list element). Note that combinations will deal with both `[a:b]` or `[a:[b,c]]` correctly:

`[[a, [c, d]], [b, [e, f]]]*.combinations()` = `[[[a, c], [a, d]], [[b, e], [b, f]]]`

Transpose the lists so that we end up with abab instead of aabb (though nested somewhat):

`[[[a, c], [a, d]], [[b, e], [b, f]]].transpose()` = `[[[a, c], [b, e]], [[a, d], [b, f]]]`

Flatten the nested lists (using spread again to flatten nested lists,but not the whole list):

`[[[a, c], [b, e]], [[a, d], [b, f]]]*.flatten()` = `[[a, c, b, e], [a, d, b, f]]`

Spread `toSpreadMap` to convert this list into a list of maps.

`[[a, c, b, e], [a, d, b, f]]*.toSpreadMap()` = `[*:[b:e, a:c], *:[b:f, a:d]]`

Answer (score 2):

Define some functions:

```
// call a 2-element list a "pair"

// convert a map entry (where entry.value can be 
// a single string or a list of strings) into a list of pairs
def pairs(entry) {
  if (entry.value instanceof String)
    return [[entry.key, entry.value]]
  entry.value.collect { [entry.key, it]}
}

// convert list of pairs to a map
def toMap(pairs) {
  pairs.inject([:]){ m,i -> m[i[0]] = i[1]; m }
}

// kind of like transpose but doesn't stop with shortest list. 
// (would like to find a less ugly way of doing this)
def mytranspose(lists) {
  def retval = []
  def mx = lists.inject(0){x, i -> i.size() > x ? i.size() : x}
  for (int i = 0; i < mx; i++) {
    def row = []
    lists.each { lst ->
      if (lst.size() > i) row << lst[i]
    }
    retval << row
  }
  retval
}
```

then put it together and test it:

```
groovy:000> m = [a: ["c","d"], b: ["e","f"]]
groovy:000> mytranspose(m.entrySet().collect{pairs(it)}).collect{toMap(it)}
===> [{a=c, b=e}, {a=d, b=f}]
```

Map entries that are strings work, and map entry lists can be different lengths:

```
groovy:000> m['g'] = 'h'
===> h
groovy:000> m['x'] = ['s', 't', 'u', 'v']
===> [s, t, u, v]
groovy:000> m
===> {a=[c, d], b=[e, f], g=h, x=[s, t, u, v]}
groovy:000> mytranspose(m.entrySet().collect{pairs(it)}).collect{toMap(it)}
===> [{a=c, b=e, g=h, x=s}, {a=d, b=f, x=t}, {x=u}, {x=v}]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't handle the case when the value is not a Map, but is a String.  "If there is only one item the list is no longer a list and it is a string." Also, Your example results in `[[[a:c], [b:e]], [[a:d], [b:f]]]`. This should be `[ [a:"c", b:"e"], [a:"d",b:"f"] ]`

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I ended up doing. If anyone has a better solution, let me know and I will accept it as the answer.

```
  Map xyz = [a: ["c","d"], b: ["e","f"]]

  List result = []

    Closure updateMap = { list, index, key, value ->
        if ( !(list[index] instanceof Map) ) {
            list[index] = [:]
        }
        list[index]."$key" = value
    }

    xyz.each { k, v ->
        if (v instanceof ArrayList) {
            v.eachWithIndex { val, idx ->
                updateMap(result, idx, k, val)
            }
        }
        else {
            updateMap(result, 0, k, v)
        }
    }
```